# Java Graphics library, how to size drawString

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt

im new to awt and string, and I am trying to draw a string but I dont know how to size it.

This is what I have done:

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawString("$", x, y);}
```

So the $ comes up, but it is very small, I want to make the string same as an oval I made

```
g.fillOval(applex,appley,unitSize,unitSize);
```

Any tips? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a font to increase the size.  Check out the [Font](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Font.html#Font(java.lang.String,int,int)) class in the Javadoc to see the options.

```
g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 72));
```

Also, if you cast `g` to `Graphics2D` and use `RenderingHints`, you can turn on `anti-aliasing` to visually smooth out your shapes, etc.

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
```